# SQL how do I Check to see if row has that data in table with on a specific grade, and if it does put a Y in another table with that field name

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hello This is my question,

just taking 2 columns from table 1, and comparing the grade, and what element is present in the CHEM field, and then placing it a Y if it is present in the corresponding Element field. I'm not sure how to do in SQL, below is an example.

In SQL:

Table 1:

| Grade | Chem |
| --- | --- |
| A30134 | AL |
| AS0134 | CR |
| AS3021 | MO |
| AS3011 | CR |

Table 2:

| Grade | AL | CR | MO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A30134 | Y | Y |  |
| AS3021 |  |  | Y |
| AS3011 |  | Y |  |

So basically, just taking 2 columns from table 1, and comparing the grade, and what element is present in the CHEM field, and then placing it a Y if it is present in the corresponding Element field.

```
UPDATE Table1 INNER JOIN 
Table2
(ON Table1.Grade =  Table2.Grade) AND (ON I'm not sure how I indicate check field compared to a data cell)
SET Table1.AL = Y;
```

Comment: Your two tables will hold the same information, but in different forms. Table 2 appears to be merely a pivot of Table 1. Is there any reason you need to store your data twice? I feel like it would be best here to just place a pivot on top of your existing `Table 1` when you need to view your data in this other format/schema, rather then store it twice.

Comment: @JNevill Yes I am sorry for not posting the full information, but I am just trying to understand how to do this because I am learning SQL this is just an example, I made up for this context.

Comment: chaeck CHASE syntax in where conditions

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest method is correlated subqueries:

```
UPDATE Table1 
    SET Table1.AL = IIF(EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.Grade = Table2.Grade AND Table2.Chem = "AL"), "Y", NULL),
        Table1.CR = IIF(EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.Grade = Table2.Grade AND Table2.Chem = "CR"), "Y", NULL),
        Table1.MO = IIF(EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.Grade = Table2.Grade AND Table2.Chem = "MO"), "Y", NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your example you may give a try to below `SQL`.

```
UPDATE Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Grade = Table2.Grade SET 
Table2.AL = IIf(DCount("[Grade]","[Table1]","[Grade]='" & table2.Grade & "' AND [Chem]='AL'")>0,"Y",Null), 
Table2.CR = IIf(DCount("[Grade]","[Table1]","[Grade]='" & [table2].[Grade] & "' AND [Chem]='CR'")>0,"Y",Null), 
Table2.MO = IIf(DCount("[Grade]","[Table1]","[Grade]='" & [table2].[Grade] & "' AND [Chem]='MO'")>0,"Y",Null);
```